# Why does Telegram desktop not show up when I click the icon in the upper-right menu?

Tags: telegram

On ubuntu 22.04, when I click the small blue telegram icon in the upper-right corner, there are 3 options; "Open Telegram", "Disable notifications" and "Quit Telegram". When I choose "Open Telegram" nothing happens, it does not show up. I have to use Alt-Tab to get it to show. Is there something I can do to fix this error?

Comment: So it is opening but in the background. Different issue.

Comment: The blue icon in the upper-right is only there if it is running. When you quit telegram desktop it disappears. A related problem I have is that when I get a notification about a new message and click on it, telegram desktop does not show up.